# Do you want to include your registrant information in third party Bulk Whois requests?

Tags: https

I'm buying a SSL certificate online for the first time.

I have this option...

Include your registrant information in third party Bulk Whois requests?

What does it exactly mean ?
What's Buil Whois and what should I answer ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bulk whois request would normally be performed by SPAMers, hackers, crackers, etc who are trying to find out your details (registered owner information) in bulk (along with a lot of other peoples). At every opportunity you should try to exclude yourself.

Quite why they are asking when signing up to SSL is more interesting though, as they shouldn't be in control of limiting bulk whois requests.

Comment: Uhm so I should answer "no" ? I'm buying a SSl certificate on GoDaddy and they are asking me this.. it is not very clear why they ask me ?

Comment: You can always send them an email to ask. But SSL should have nothing to do with WHOIS (although it may be on the same screen when signing up). I'd say no.